# Integrate an hosted e-commerce solution in a web site hosted on a different server

Tags: subdomain, cname-record

In mydomain.com i need to integrate an ecommerce page that i would like to be hosted by a different provider. For what I understood I have to create a subdomain store.mydomain.com from the cpanel and then a cname or an A record that point to that host. Am i right?
Thanks

Comment: Is it possible to have my question reopened after this modification?

Comment: You can flag for re-opening by using the links underneath the question tags, but this is a yes/no question so I don't know what more can be added.

Answer (score 2):

Yes - you're right, that's what you need to do.